# css for leaving space among two button tag

Tags: html, css

I want to leave some space among two buttons which is in div tag.I tried lot but still having problem.I created login div which has two buttons. login div is inside header div which I marked as 'h'.I want to leave some space among two buttons where I rounded in green.But now I drawn current displayed location in red color.

```css
.login{
    margin:0;
    padding:0px 10px 10px 0px;
    text-align:right;
    width:40%;
    position:absolute; 
  right:0;
  bottom:0;

}
.login button
{
   padding:0px 10px 10px 0px;   
 }
```

```html
<div class="header">
   <div class="login">
        <button class="add">login</button>
        <button class="upload">Enquiry</button>
   </div>  <!--end of login div -->
</div>  <!--end of header div -->
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**like this type**

```css
.login{
    margin:0;
    padding:0px 10px 10px 0px;
    text-align:right;
    width:40%;
    position:absolute; 
  right:0;
  bottom:0;

}
.login button
{
   padding:0px 10px 10px 0px;   
   margin-left: 10px;
 }
```

```html
<div class="header">
   <div class="login">
        <button class="add">login</button>
        <button class="upload">Enquiry</button>
   </div>  <!--end of login div -->
</div>  <!--end of header div -->
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 .login button
 {
    margin-left:10px;   
 }
```

add some left-margin?

Comment: padding-left: 2cm;  leave some space before text.

Comment: use margin-left instead :)

Answer (score 1):

ok try this.....i hope this will be okey...

```
  .login button
 {
  margin-left:10px;

 padding:0px 10px 10px 0px;   
 }
```

This is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/41fhejfd/4/

Comment: &nbsp is not validated by validator

Comment: It is `&nbsp;` not `&nbsp`.

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```
.login button {
   margin-left: 30px;  
}
```

Or you could add a container around your buttons, give that a width, and then float them to the `left` and `right` sides.

The HTML:

```
<div class="header">
   <div class="login">
       <div class=logincontainer>
           <button class="add">login</button>
           <button class="upload">Enquiry</button>
       </div>
   </div>  <!--end of login div -->
</div>  <!--end of header div -->
```

The CSS:

```
.logincontainer {
    width: 200px;
}
.add {
    float: left;
}
.upload {
    float: right;
}
```